# Comparing two curves

Tags: r, curve

I have a data (ge3_ratio) with 86 observations measuring the ratio of phonological errors produced by children. The data was collected from spontaneous speech transcripts from 3 children aged 21 to 65 months. The data look like this:

| age | child | Transcripts | Process | Liq | n | ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Luana | 1 | posteriorização | N | 1 | 1.0000000 |
| 23 | Luana | 1 | apagamento de líquida | S | 1 | 1.0000000 |
| 24 | Leonardo | 1 | apagamento de líquida | S | 1 | 1.0000000 |
| 24 | Túlio | 3 | assimilação + apagamento de líquida | S | 1 | 0.3333333 |
| 24 | Túlio | 3 | metátese | S | 1 | 0.3333333 |
| 24 | Túlio | 3 | semivocalização de líquidas | S | 1 | 0.3333333 |
| 24 | Túlio | 3 | substituição de líquida | S | 1 | 0.3333333 |
| 25 | Túlio | 2 | anteriorização | N | 1 | 0.5000000 |
| 25 | Túlio | 2 | apagamento de líquida | S | 1 | 0.5000000 |
| 26 | Luana | 1 | apagamento de líquida | S | 1 | 1.0000000 |

The ratio column was created dividing n by Transcripts. The column Liq describes whether the phonological error (Process) involves a liquid consonant (coded as S) or not (coded as N). I want to test the hypothesis that phonological errors involving liquid consonants last for longer than those not involving them. "Last for longer" does not mean only that the curve length will be greater for S than for N, but also that the ratio must be greater for S than for N as the child grows older. I have the following graphs showing this development path ("Liquida" just means "Liquid"):

```r
ggplot(ge3_ratio, aes(age, ratio, color = Liq)) + 
  geom_smooth() + scale_color_manual(values = kb) + 
   labs(x = "age in months")
ggplot(ge3_ratio, aes(age, ratio, color = Liq)) + 
  geom_path() + scale_color_manual(values = kb) + 
  labs(x = "age in months")
```

geom_smooth:
[image: geom_smooth]

geom_path:
[image: geom_path]

I want help as how to proceed with the analysis (taking into account my hypothesis), which tests I can run and how to do that in R. I started reading about growth curve analysis, but I am unsure about how I can apply the concepts in my data.

Comment: this question seems more appropriate as a Cross Validated post since this isn't a programming question but more of analytical request for guidance. The question may be better suited there rather than on S.O.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my mistake! I just posted my question there.